# Fecha distinta a hoy JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, spring-tool-suite

estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación web.

Tengo una tabla y quiero poner el fondo de la fila de otro color cuando la fecha es diferente a la de hoy.

Mi JS es:

```
var hoy = new Date();
var dd = hoy.getDate();
var mm = hoy.getMonth() + 1;

if (dd < 10) {
      dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    
if (mm < 10) {
     mm = '0' + mm;
}
var hoyFormat = dd + '/' + mm;
```

El JSP es:

```
<c:set var="color" value="#fa8072" />
<c:set var="testHoy" value="${hoyFormat}" />
  <c:forEach items="${producciones}" var="produccion">
    <c:if                                            
       test="${fn:contains(produccion.fechaplanificacion, testHoy)}">
         <c:set var="color" value="#ffffff" />
    </c:if>

<tr bgcolor="${color}">
```

Que estoy haciendo mal? ya que la fecha cuando es distinta a la de hoy no se pinta del color #fa8072

Quiero añadir que produccion.fechaplanificacion tiene formato "2023-02-02 08:00:00.000" (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss:mmmm) aunque en el jsp lo añado a la tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
<td><fmt:formatDate                                                          
   value="${produccion.fechaplanificacion}"
   pattern="dd/MM HH:mm" /></td>
```

Me podríais ayudar?

Comment: Recuerda que el JSP se insterpreta en el backend, resultando en HTML, y el código JS se ejecuta una vez que el HTML se ha cargado **en en el cliente**.

Comment: @PabloLozano He hecho una modificación y le paso la fecha desde el controller "model.addAttribute("hoy", variosServ.fechaHoy());"... Aun así, no funciona el fn:contains ....      c:set var = "fechaprod" value="${produccion.fechaplanificacion}"/>              
   <c:if
     test="${fn:contains(fechaprod, hoy)}">
        <c:set var="color" value="#fa8072" />
   </c:if>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comento como lo he solucionado por si a alguien le sirve de ayuda.

Calculo la fecha actual en el backend (Service) y en el acceso a datos (De donde saco produccion.fechaplanificacion) he añadido una variable boolean (produccion.fechadistinta) en la que almaceno "false" si produccion.fechaplanificacion.toString().Contains(hoy) y si no contiene la fecha de hoy, almaceno "true"

Luego, en el JSP, hago lo siguiente

```
<c:if test="${produccion.fechadistinta == true}">
     <c:set var="color" value="#fa8072" /> 
</c:if>
```